# How to align about the colon in each line of text like movie credits often do

Tags: css

I would like to align a few line of text about the colon in each line. So I have this:

```
aaa:111
bbbbbbb:22222
cccccccccc:33333333
dd:44
eeee:5555
```

I want them to align about the colon:

```
       aaa:111
   bbbbbbb:22222
cccccccccc:33333333
        dd:44
      eeee:5555
```

So far I can manage it with a table and two columns, the left column text-align:right, and the right column text-align left. But I am so sure that there are much more elegant solutions than this. -- Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have tabular content.  So a table sounds like a reasonable solution (IMO).

Comment: A table will do here, since you are dealing with tabular data. Tables do have their place in design - not everything needs to be pure CSS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy and semantic way would be to use a definition list:

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2216403)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

dt {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}

dt:after {
  content: ':';
}

dd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>aaa</dt>
  <dd>111</dd>
  <dt>bbbbbbb</dt>
  <dd>22222</dd>
  <dt>cccccccccc</dt>
  <dd>33333333</dd>
  <dt>dd</dt>
  <dd>44</dd>
  <dt>eeee</dt>
  <dd>5555555</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: I like the semantic part quite a bit. so I guess the main ingredient is having  text-align:right and width set for the text to the left of the colon.

Comment: Any way to add a bit more space to the right of the colon? No matter where I add spaces, margins or paddings, it doesn't seem to work. It's just a tad too tight for my taste.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that whatever wraps those two classes has enough room here - 300px + any padding or margin.

```css
.label-wrap {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

.info {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="label-wrap">aaa:</div>
<div class="info">111</div>
```

Comment: If you are to go this way, you can also use `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` to get a proper semantic markup.

Comment: This is way better ... it is obfuscating to use <dl> which has whole different use and just to style it away

Answer (score 3):

If your data is tabular data, then your approach with using tables is an acceptable one.

However an alternative would be to use HTML spans:

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F2PRN/1/

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>aaa:</span>111
</p>
<p>
  <span>bbbbbbb:</span>22222
</p>
<p>
  <span>cccccccccc:</span>33333333
</p>
```

Comment: My understanding is that the `<label>` tag is intended for use with `<input>`s. You could just as easily use a `<span>` instead.

Comment: @chipcullen Good point, I've updated my answer. I think I simply chose labels as the designed follows form fields

Answer (score 1):

with arbitrary value length, a table would be the only way to do it

Comment: Not the only way, just the only sane way. ;) Could definitely create a fake table using `div`s and Javascript.

Comment: Yes but then you are still using a "table" even if it is made of divs