# Align around a given character in bash

Tags: bash, alignment, zsh

Is there an easy way to align multiple rows of text about a single character, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891414/how-to-align-about-the-colon-in-each-line-of-text-like-movie-credits-often-do), but in bash.

Also open to zsh solutions.

What I have:

```
aaa:aaaaaaaa
bb:bbb
cccccccccccc:cc
d:d
```

What I want:

```
         aaa:aaaaaaaa
          bb:bbb
cccccccccccc:cc
           d:d
```

Preferably the output can be piped out and retain its layout too.

Comment: It's not the format you're asking for, but you might want to try the output of `column -s ':' -o ':' -t` or even `column -s ':' -t` (the first one is close, but the text isn't right-aligned ; the second one is nicer to look IMO, but it omits the `:`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with column and gnu sed

```
column -t -s':' infile | sed -E 's/(\S+)(\s{0,})(  )(.*)/\2\1:\4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell itself does not seem like a particularly suitable tool for this task. Using an external tool makes for a solution which is portable between shells. Here is a simple Awk solution.

```
awk -F ':' '{ a[++n] = $1; b[n] = $2; if (length($1) > max) max = length($1) }
  END { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%" max "s:%s\n", a[i], b[i] }'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Eaebhh

This stores the input file in memory; if you need to process large amount of text, it would probably be better to split this into a two-pass script (first pass, just read all the lines to get `max`, then change the `END` block to actually print output from the second pass), which then requires the input to be seekable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on BSD/Linux you can do

```bash
column -t -s: -o: -R 1
```

as shown with long options in

```bash
printf '
aaa:aaaaaaaa
bb:bbb
cccccccccccc:cc
d:d' |
  column --table \
         --separator : \
         --output-separator : \
         --table-right 1
```